# Receiver 'ViewController' for class message is a forward declaration error in appdelegate class

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I used s`hareddelegate` method,while running the app I got the  Unknown type name `'ViewController'`; did you mean `'UIViewController'`? then I use the `@class ViewController` but now I got the above error how can I solve.

In the below `@property(nonatomic,strong) nstring *title1;` I used in tableview to share data to detailview.

Please help me.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//#import "ViewController.h"

@class ViewController;
#define UIAPPDelegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{

}

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *title1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isFirstTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
//@property(strong,nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end

//did finish with lanching page.
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    isFirstTime = YES;

    sleep(3);

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    title1=[[NSString alloc]init];
    self.viewController= [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If you really comment out the `#import` statement, the compiler has no way to figure out that `ViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` and, as a result, it doesn't expect it to have `initWithNibName:` method.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to add this before you use in .m file.

@class will be used for to inform the compiler as

**"I'm having that viewController class, don't expect me to import in .h file"**

Compiler says

**"OK. I didn't.But You will have to import it and let me know this before you use it."**

So before you use it in .m file,You will have to add/import this before you use in .m file.

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
```

Comment: #import "ViewController.h" i got the error Unknown type name 'ViewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?

Comment: check if you have added viewController.h .m in your project. then go to viewController.h file you should see @interface  ViewController : UIViewController